# IIS Express configuration error "failed to register URL"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I have a following configuration in my `applicationhost.config` file, note 3 binding entries:

```
<sites>
    <site name="MyFleet.Web-Site" id="4">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\Roman\Documents\My Web Sites\xxx.Web-Site42" />
        </application>
        <application path="/MyFleet" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\projects\xxx\xxx\app\xxx.Web" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:xxx.ddns.com" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
    </siteDefaults>
    <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
    <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

When I try to launch the app - it gives me this error: [image]

To fix this, I would remove `http` binding entry from the configuration file and everything works until I reopen solution in VS2017 at which point it re-adds `http` binding, and complains about it when I start the app.

Question: How do I fix this (by either preventing VS from adding the binding, or making it work with that `http` binding)?

InB4: 
1. I have verified there are no other `44300` occurrences in this config file.
2. I have verified there are no other `*.config` files on my computer (using grep) that contain `:44300` text.

Comment: Project Diagnostics might reveal what's up, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html Generally speaking, your project file (.csproj) might still contain a reference to 44300.

Answer (score 0):

Port should be different if there are  multiple bindings in applicationhost.config in .vs folder.